# FIRST FRIDAY OF THE YEAR

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula to calculate the first Friday of the Year and it works okay.
I understand how the formula gets the answer however, I can't seem to find the reasoning behind the formula. The formula is:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2))
```

This gives us 2020/01/08 - 5 = 2020/01/03 which is the First Friday of the Year. But why does the formula choose 8 and 2 as the dates?
Can someone please explain the reason.

Answer (score 2):

The first, obvious, part of the formula is that `DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,8)` gives you the eighth day of the month which can't be the first Friday since one of the 7 days before it would must be a Friday.

My guess is that the second part has a little bit of kludgery going on. `WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))` would give you the number of days from the first day of the month to the previous Sunday. But if you're looking for the previous Saturday you'd need `WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)) + 1` or `WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2))`.

Finally, the day of the week `WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2))` before the 1st of the month is the same day of the week before the 8th of the month.

Answer (score 0):

This works because the 8th day cannot be the first Friday.
If the year starts with Sunday being the 1st day then the day you are looking for is 2 days before the 8th day.

So, if the 8th day is Sunday, because the year starts on Sunday 1/1, then 2 days before that is Friday, which will be the first Friday.

Such that:

```
Date(Year(Today(),1,1) = 1/1/2023 (First Sunday)
Date(Year(Today(),1,8) = 1/8/2023 (Second Sunday)
Date(Year(Today(),1,2) = 1/2/2023 (First Monday)
Weekday(1/2/2023) = 2 (Monday)
```

So, 1/8/2023 - 2 days = 1/6/2023 (First Friday).

This works for any year even if it doesn't start with Sunday being Jan 1.

Example 2022:

```
Date(2022,1,1) = 1/1/2022 (First Saturday)
Date(2022,1,8) = 1/8/2022 (Second Saturday)
Date(2022,1,2) = 1/2/2022 ( First Sunday)
Weekday(1/2/2022) = 1 (Sunday)
```

So, 1/8/2022 (Saturday) - 1 day = 1/7/2022 (First Friday of 2022)